# Get WMS layer by user defined ID

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have a map where i'm loading several WMS layers from different urls.  I'm trying to figure out a way to turn each layer on/off by an identifier, but i can't figure out how to add a unique identifier to the layer, or source of the layer.  Basically i have:

```
for (const entry of entries) {
    const tileWMSOptions = {
              url: entry.URL,
              params: { LAYERS: layerNames, TILED: true },  
            };
            const layer = new TileLayer({
              source: new TileWMS(tileWMSOptions),
            });
            mapObj.addLayer(layer);
}
```

my 'entry' object has an ID that i would like to associate with this layer, so that i can do some sort of

```
map.getLayers();
```

run through them, and do something specific if the id of that layer matches what i'm looking for.  I don't see any way of doing this from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile-TileLayer.html or https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileWMS.html .  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your own properties in the layer (similar to `title` in the documentation http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile-TileLayer.html )

```
layer = new TileLayer({
              source: new TileWMS(tileWMSOptions),
              guid: guid
            });
```

and retrieve using .get

```
map.getLayers().getArray()[0].get('guid');
```

Comment: Thanks, dumb mistake.  Forget i'm working in javascript sometimes!